# A map from the set of binary strings to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $B$ is the set of all finite strings of $0$'s and $1$'s. Define a binary relation $R$ on $B$ as follows: $$\sigma R\tau\quad\mbox{ iff }\quad\mbox{ $\sigma$ is a proper initial segment of $\tau$}$$ for all $\sigma ,\tau\in B$.

Then, does there exist a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and a function $f\colon B\to\mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following conditions:

- For all $\sigma\in B,\hspace{2mm}$$f(\sigma )\in S$ iff $\sigma$ starts with a $1$ i.e. $\sigma =1\tau$ for some $\tau$ in $B$.
- For all $\sigma ,\tau\in B$,$\hspace{2 mm}$ if $\sigma R\tau$ then $f(\sigma )<f(\tau )$
- For all $\sigma\in B$ and $n\in\mathbb{N},\hspace{2 mm}$ if $f(\sigma )<n$ then  there exists $\tau\in B$ such that $\sigma R\tau$ and $f(\tau )=n.$

I have tried some functions, like length of the string, number of zeroes, equivalent integer form etc. with $S$ to be the set of even/odd integers, but none of them seems to work. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What does "proper initial segment" mean?

Comment: @abiessu, I assume "abc" is a proper initial segment of "abcd". "abcd" would be initial, but not proper. "cd" would be proper but not initial.

Comment: @abiessu:$\sigma_1$ is a proper initial segment of $\sigma$ if $\sigma= \sigma_1\sigma_2$ for some $\sigma_2\in B$ and $\sigma_1\ne\sigma$; eg. 00101 is a proper initial segment of 0010111001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $i \in S$. Say $\sigma \in B$, $f(\sigma) < i$ and $\sigma$ starts with $0$. Then, by third property, there exists $\tau \in B$, $f(\tau) = i$ and $\sigma R \tau$. Because $i$ was in $S$, $\tau$ starts with $1$. Because $\sigma R \tau$, $\sigma$ also starts with $1$. That's a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I guess, to get a over all contradiction we need $S$ to be infinite, which of course is true by the second condition.